# Using Moq to unit test Controller Routing function in MVC6

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I am currently learning to use Moq for unit test and have a problem when I try to unit test the routing function in controllers. I actually followed the instructions in http://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/how-to-successfully-mock-httpcontext-BT. The cold is as follow:

```
        RouteCollection routes = new RouteCollection();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routes);
        moqRequest.Setup(e => e.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Returns("~/Home/Index");
        RouteData routeData = routes.GetRouteData(moqContext.Object);
        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(routeData);
        Assert.AreEqual("Home", routeData.Values["controller"]);
        Assert.AreEqual("Index", routeData.Values["action"]);
```

However, I am not able to find RouteConfig in Asp.Net5 + MVC6. I saw some articles using MvcApplication, rather than RouteConfig, but I was also not able to find it.Can anyone help to direct me to some articles relating to this problem or help to solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes` is not part of the MVC6 template. The instructions you are following are for an earlier version of the MVC framework

Comment: Hi Nkosi, Than you for your reply. May I ask if you have any idea how to do the mock test for the routing function in MVC6? Thanks.

Comment: Well you can try to recreate what the `RegisterRoutes` did in arranging your test. Which was basically what the name implies. register routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the following answer

[Unit testing routing in ASP.NET Core 1.0 (ex MVC 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33833704/5233410)

Where they suggest integration/functional testing with bootstrapping the start up in order to test routes.

Comment: Hi Nkosi, thank you for showing me the sample code. However, it looks like that in MVC6, routes does not have the MapRoute function. The closest function is MapPageRoute.

Comment: Here is the source code for routing in MVC6. A lot has changed from MVC5 to 6 so this should show you what applies to MVC6 https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing

Comment: Here is another article about Routing in MVC6. Take a look at how to set it up and then you can try to mock the needed parts for testing http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing

Comment: Here is the source code of of the `MapRoute` extensions. https://github.com/aspnet/Routing/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing/MapRouteRouteBuilderExtensions.cs

Comment: Thank you Nkosi. It is so nice to receive your help. It is true that there are a lot of changes from MVC5 to MVC6. Eventually, I solve the problem by an answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114999/unit-testing-routing-in-asp-net-core-1-0-ex-mvc-6. In this answer, it suggested to use the code in the source code of MVC6, especially the Startup.cs, RoutingTests.cs, TestResponseGenerator and some other related files. The RoutingTests.cs can be found in https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/6.0.0-rc1/test/WebSites/RoutingWebSite/Startup.cs. Thanks again for your kind help.

Comment: OK cool. I'll update my answer to direct people to the answer